# Using icon and text in html <a> tag, how do I change the text font?

Tags: html, css

So I'm writing a personal website to help myself learn html and css, and as part of that, I'm trying to put in some contact links. For these I want them to have an icon and text. I'm using the font awesome icons to achieve this. As of right now, I have the links working properly, but for some reason, the text in the links is a serif font, when the rest of my site is a sans serif font. Additionally, one fo the links is bolded constantly, when it's only supposed to be bolded when hovered over. This is what it looks like (boxes added to protect my info):

[Screenshot from webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3x3Y.png)

Here's my HTML and related CSS code:

```css
    a {
      color:#263fb9;
      text-decoration:none;
      font-family: "Noto Sans", Monaco, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Lucida Console, Terminal, Consolas, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace;
      }

    a:hover, a:focus {
      color:#111e5c;
      font-weight: bold;
      }

    .fa {
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-radius: 50%;
      font-family: "Noto Sans", Monaco, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Lucida Console, Terminal, Consolas, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace;
      }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <a href="mailto:EMAIL ADDRESS" class="fas fa-envelope" > EMAIL ADDRESS</a>
        
    <a href="https://twitter.com/HANDLE" class="fab fa-twitter" > HANDLE</a>
```

(Note: all of this was adapted from the Jekyll "Minimal" theme from github pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add the `fa` class to the a tag, use an extra element:

```
<a href="mailto:EMAIL ADDRESS" class="" > <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span> EMAIL ADDRESS</a>
```

Comment: Hi! thank you so much! this fixed the font issue, but now the icons themselves aren't showing up (they're just little boxes). Any idea? EDIT: Nevermind! that was because of something else I had screwed up elsewhere! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in this case is that the classes you are adding to your link (the FontAwesome classes) end up modifying your font-family definition for the element.

So, what you could do in this case is use something like this:

```html
<a href="https://twitter.com/HANDLE"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> HANDLE</a>
```